# how to create span element in web page contained in an iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a scenario where a javascript function creates a new span element in web page present in main window of browser--

Code for this is given below--

```
  document.createElement('span');
```

Now I want to extend this code to make it work in an iframe as well... I have figured out that for this to happen, the above code should be modified so that the span element is created within the iframe. I have with me the id/name of the iframe in which the span element has to be created... How do I create the span element in iframe?

I understand that the web page in iframe should belong to same domain as page contained in main window(viz Same Origin Policy)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i get u right u need to add an element in a page in iframe

use this code

```
var ifrm= document.getElementById('iframe id');
var ifrmdocument = ifrm.contentWindow.document;
var spn=ifrmdocument.createElement('span');
spn.innerHTML='Hello';
ifrmdocument.appendChild(spn);
```

Regards

Any Questions iam here

if my answer is useful please mark it as correct one

Comment: I just tested this code on Firefox browser and it throws an exception on var ifrmdocument = ifrm.contentWindow.document; Please tell me how to fix this code on Firefox. Thanks.

Comment: please tell me a version of FF you use ??